# Way to create object with default values

Tags: java

I have some classes with variables defined right after //class Foo{
In the other class is created object of above class. After one minute I need to reset variables in Foo to default values. 
I tried to just create new object, nothing happens. Is there any other way than creating a setter?

Comment: Um...huh?! (Code is worth a thousand words...)

Comment: Can we see some code please, I have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve

Comment: There's a myriad of ways ranging from the obvious to the bizarre.

Comment: I have two classes, in first is thread that changing values of variables. Now I need to restore default values, declared at the start of program
    class Name { int x = 5; } Thread is changing that value, I need to restore it from the other class, without any method. Hope you understood my poor english :P

Comment: @AdrianMarszałek: To improve your question, use the "edit" link. You'll need to do a lot more than that comment to make this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have these default values stored in some other place, you can't recover the default values. Use a timer to reload these vars.

```
// some untested code
class A {
    final int x_DEFAULT = 0;
    int x = 0;

    void reloadVars() {
        x = x_DEFAULT;
    }

    A() {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                reloadVars();
            }
        }, 60000, 60000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh.. of course. It's so obvious and it's too late for thinking ^^

Comment: I don't remember Java having `const` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. It is too much time away from Java, const exists in other languages I work now. =)

Comment: A much more straightforward solution is to just have an `init()` method that you call from the constructor and from the `run()` method. The `init()` method initializes your vars.